# I am trying to calculate the total for each line item, but it only calculates the first total in the array a single time when changing the quantity

Tags: angular, formarray

component.ts

I am not sure why my for loop is not calculating the total for each item in the array?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.billLineItemsQuantityOnChange(this.billLineItems);
}

get billLineItems(): FormArray {
  return this.billForm.get('billLineItems') as FormArray;
}

calculateBillLineItemsTotal(billLineItems: FormArray): void {
  for(let i = 0; i <= billLineItems.length; i++) {
    const amount = billLineItems.at(i).get(['amount']);
    const quantity = billLineItems.at(i).get(['quantity']);
    const total = billLineItems.at(i).get(['total']);
    const calcTotal = amount!.value * quantity!.value;
    total!.setValue(calcTotal)
  }
}

billLineItemsQuantityOnChange(billLineItems: FormArray): void {
  for(let i = 0; i <= billLineItems.length; i++) {
    const amount = billLineItems.at(i).get(['amount']);
    const quantity = billLineItems.at(i).get(['quantity']);
    quantity!.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (amount!.value !== null && quantity!.value !== null) {
        this.calculateBillLineItemsTotal(billLineItems);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: what is the **!** in amount!.value?

Comment: @malbarmavi

I can try to, essentially what i am trying to is, in my form Array, i am trying to calculate the total for a form group based on the quantity changing only for that form group.

Comment: @malbarmavi

here is the stackblitz demo 

I was able to get the total to calculate for all form groups in the array, but can only be done by changing the quantity value of the first form group.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9cjnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: check my answer I have change the calculation logic to simpler version 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the calculation logic place to createBillLineItem method  instated of keep looping throw controls and I set the subsection to the value change for quantity and amount before return the form Group

```js
  createBillLineItem(): FormGroup {

    const fg  =this.fb.group({
      description: [null],
      amount: 0,
      quantity:0,
      total: 0,
    });

     fg.get('quantity').valueChanges.subscribe((qty) => {
       const amount  = +fg.get('amount').value || 0 ;
       fg.get('total').setValue(amount * +qty)
      });


     fg.get('quantity').valueChanges.subscribe((amount) => {
       const qty  = +fg.get('amount').value || 0 ;
       fg.get('total').setValue(amount * +qty)
      });

    return fg;
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr165b)